# NpgsqlConnection query doesn't join tables in .net core application

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i connect to `PostgreSQL` database and want to get data from three tables.

This is how I do it:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetResults<T>()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> items = new List<T>();
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn =
            new NpgsqlConnection(_configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("PGConnectionResultDb")))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                items = conn.Query<T>(@"select a.id,
                            a.parent_id,
                            a.results,
                            a.status,
                            a.errormessage,
                            a.tablename,
                            b.test_type,
                            c.name,
                            c.start_date,
                            c.end_date
                            from a
                            join b 
                            on a.parent_id = b.id
                            join c
                            on c.id = b.parent_id").ToList();

                Console.WriteLine(items);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }

            return items;
        }
```

The query works well when I execute it in `DBeaver` as sql command, however my method return `NULL` values from **Tables b and c**. it only puts values for table `a` and doesn't join other tables. Why it's not working ir the query is correct?

This is what data I get: 
[image]

And these underlined values are not `NULL` in database

Comment: It seems *very* unlikely that this is a provider bug, and much more likely that either the query is wrong, or that your `catch {}` is swallowing the real problem. What makes you think the problem here is *in the provider*? (note: it certainly isn't `entity-framework` or `asp.net-core` (tags), since they aren't involved). We don't have your tables or data, so we can't run it locally to see what you get. But: if you run the query **via the standalone postgres query tools**: what do you get? Also ... it *looks* like this is using "Dapper" - is that a correct guess?

Comment: Calling `Console.WriteLine(items);` on a list won't print out the list. It will print out the variable's type. How did you check what the query returns? BTW `catch{}` will hide any exceptions thrown. Your code may be throwing which is why the method returns an empty  list

Comment: What do you see when you run this, and what did you *expect* to see when you run this?

Comment: I updated my question with picture of the data I retrieve